# Why does this nginx/thin run puppet master interpret paths differently than a lone puppetmasterd?

Tags: debian, nginx, puppet, thin

For the purposes of this question I need to make a distinction between my
Production puppet master and my Development puppet master. In either
case, my /etc/puppet/puppet.conf is:

```
[main]
ssldir=$vardir/ssl

[master]
certname=puppet
```

Development puppet master is run:

```
# puppetmasterd --debug --no-daemonize
```

and Production puppet master is a thin/nginx affair. The relevant nginx configuration files:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
upstream puppet-production {
    server   unix:/var/run/puppet/master.00.sock;
    server   unix:/var/run/puppet/master.01.sock;
    server   unix:/var/run/puppet/master.02.sock;
}

server {
    listen puppet:8140;
    include conf.d/puppet_ssl.conf;
    include conf.d/puppet_proxy_set_header.conf;

    default_type application/x-raw;

    location /production/file_content/ {
        rewrite ^/production/file_content/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/files/$2;
        break;
        root /etc/puppet/modules/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://puppet-production;
    }
}
```

and

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/puppet_proxy_set_header.conf 
proxy_redirect         off; 
proxy_set_header Host              $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  $ssl_client_verify;
proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
```

and

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/puppet_ssl.conf

ssl on; 
ssl_certificate /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet.pem;
ssl_ciphers ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
ssl_client_certificate  /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem;
ssl_verify_client       on;
```

The relevant thin configuration files:

```
#/etc/puppet/config.ru 

# a config.ru, for use with every rack-compatible webserver.
# SSL needs to be handled outside this, though.

# if puppet is not in your RUBYLIB:
# $:.unshift('/opt/puppet/lib')

$0 = "master"

# if you want debugging:
# ARGV << "--debug"

ARGV << "--rack"
require 'puppet/application/master'
# we're usually running inside a Rack::Builder.new {} block,
# therefore we need to call run *here*.
run Puppet::Application[:master].run
```

and

```
# /etc/supervisor/conf.d/puppetmaster.conf 

# This file is autogenerated by Puppet. Manual changes will be overwritten!
[program:puppetmaster]
command=/usr/bin/thin start -e development --socket /var/run/puppet/master.%(process_num)02d.sock --user puppet --group puppet --chdir /etc/puppet -R /etc/puppet/config.ru
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=3
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=3
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=10
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/puppetmaster/puppetmaster.out
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=250MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/puppetmaster/puppetmaster.err
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=250MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

---

Using [puppet-module-supervisor](https://github.com/plathrop/puppet-module-supervisor) I find that
the source line path in `manifests/init.pp` causes a 404 when running in
Production mode:

```
'/etc/logrotate.d/supervisor':
 source => 'puppet:///modules/supervisor/logrotate',
 require => Package[$supervisor::params::package];
```

but if I modify the path to be simply `puppet:///supervisor/logrotate`
all is well. The first and second form succeed in Development mode.
It's my understanding that the first form is *correct* and that my
Production mode should have no issues with it.

Running `puppet agent --test` when master is configured in Production
mode results in:

```
# puppet agent --test
info: Caching catalog for puppet.troutwine.us
info: Applying configuration version '1327957286'
err: /Stage[main]/Supervisor/File[/etc/logrotate.d/supervisor]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file on ensure: Error 404 on SERVER: <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.8</center>
</body>
</html>
 at /etc/puppet/modules/supervisor/manifests/init.pp:32
notice: Finished catalog run in 1.65 seconds
```

and the logs from `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

```
# cat /var/log/nginx/{access,error}.log
127.0.1.1 - - [30/Jan/2012:20:50:58 +0000] "POST /production/catalog/puppet.troutwine.us HTTP/1.1" 200 13290 "-" "Ruby"
127.0.1.1 - - [30/Jan/2012:20:51:00 +0000] "GET  /production/file_metadata/modules/supervisor/logrotate? HTTP/1.1" 200 308 "-" "Ruby"
127.0.1.1 - - [30/Jan/2012:20:51:00 +0000] "GET /production/file_content/modules/supervisor/logrotate HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "Ruby"
127.0.1.1 - - [30/Jan/2012:20:51:01 +0000] "PUT /production/report/puppet.troutwine.us HTTP/1.1" 200 14 "-" "Ruby"

2012/01/30 20:51:00 [error] 10716#0: *222 open() "/etc/puppet/modules/modules/files/supervisor/logrotate" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.1.1, server: , request: "GET /production/file_content/modules/supervisor/logrotate HTTP/1.1", host: "puppet:8140"
```

Details about my environment:

```
# puppet --version
2.7.9
# cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.3
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i486-linux]
```

Anyone have an inkling of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that the client node is requesting is:

```
/production/file_content/modules/supervisor/logrotate
```

While the nginx config as written seems to be expecting:

```
/production/file_content/supervisor/logrotate
```

So, `modules` is caught by the first capture and `supervisor/logrotate` is caught by the second capture; the `files` that needs to go between the module name and the file name is not in the right place and `modules` gets doubled:

```
"/etc/puppet/modules/modules/files/supervisor/logrotate" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Seems like you could just change your rewrite rule to this:

```
rewrite ^/production/file_content/modules/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/files/$2;
```

Comment: D'oh! Interesting what the eye skips over. Thanks very much.